# How to query by key string instead of value in firebase?

Tags: database, firebase

I am facing a problem. I want to search a key name (not by value) in firebase database and want to get its 2nd order parent. I have no idea how to do it. If it is not possible, can you suggest any other alternative way (such as restructuring the database in a specific way or anything else) to achieve my goal using firebase? The screenshot of the structure is attached hereby.[image]

Comment: It would be great if you can share an example of how you are trying to solve the issue.
Meantime did you read this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data?

Comment: I tried `Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("exp").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");` but it seems to accept only values, not keys. I read the documentation, but all the orderby queries accept values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes a bit of reframing of the problem. Instead of saying "I want the items with this property", think of it as "I want the items with whatever value for this property".

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("exp/banana").startAt(" ")
```

Here the space (`" "`) is just the first printable character, so we're matching everything.

While this query will work, it requires that you define an index on `exp/banana` for each user. It's very likely that you'll get better results if you create an inverted index in your JSON to allow this specific lookup. For a longer explanation and an example, see my answer here: [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day.